# Displaying a pdf in a new browser tab from a Uint8Array

Tags: reactjs, pdf, blob, uint8array

**Background**

I'm generating a PDF file dynamically in the backend of my web app using `pdf-lib`. Then, I send the PDF bytes in the form of `Uint8Array` to frontend in order to open a new tab that will display the file outside of the app's frontend.

**The Problem**

While the request is successfully completed with the desired `Uint8Array` payload, there is an error alert in the new tab (Chrome) that says:
Error
Failed to load PDF document.

The `Uint8Array` data is inside the response body:

```
{
    success: true,
    data: {0: 37, 1: 80, 2: 68, 3: 70, 4: 45, ...}
}
```

**What I tried**

1. Before returning the bytes to the frontend I am able to save and access the PDF file on my PC using the `fs.readFileSync()` method.
2. I tried using both Chrome and Edge, but the problem persists.

**Backend code**

```
try {
        const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()    // .save() method returns Promise<Uint8Array>
        const filePath = './dddd.pdf'
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, pdfBytes)    // This line creates a file to PC successfully
        return pdfBytes
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('erroe while saving');
        console.log(err);
    }
```

**Frontend Code**

```
if (result.success) {
       const pdfBlob = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
       const pdfURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob)
       console.log(pdfURL);   // -->  blob:http://localhost:3000/8f168e27-934e-4d80-a479-31975e22eaa1
            
       window.open(pdfURL, '_blank')
 }
```

Comment: Did you compare the bytes you receive on the front-end with the bytes on disk on the backend? Just to confirm you really are working with the exact same data? And if you are, can chrome open that PDF if you just drop it onto Chrome or does it throw the same error? (i.e. is the PDF itself formatted in a way that Chrome can't work with)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did not compare the bytes since there is no action that is being done other than generating a PDF file using `fs` and then returning those same bytes to the frontned. Chrome can successfully open the PDF that was generated using `fs`.

Comment: @KJ so what can i do in order to convert the bytes into what you call file.pdf?

Comment: @IdoBa then just to rule things out, have a look at your on-disk PDF and show what the first, say, 20 bytes are, and show the first 20 values in your byte array in the browser, so that it's clear in your post that that's not where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems the problem is that I cant directly use the `.json()` or `JSON.stringefy()` methods on an Uint8Array and just send it to the frontend because it corrupts the binary data.

**Solution**

In the backend, I first had to convert the Uint8Array to a base64string, send the string in a json to the front end, convert the base64string back to Uint8Array and only then create the blob, create a temporary URL and open it in a new tab.

Backend code:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { generatePdf } from "@/lib/pdf/generate/generatePDF";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse , context: {}) {
    try {
        console.log(' request reached!!!');
        
        const body = await req.json()
        const pdfBytes = await generatePdf(body)
        const base64PDF = Buffer.from(pdfBytes as Uint8Array).toString('base64')
        return NextResponse.json({success: true, data: base64PDF}, { status: 200 })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error occurred while ...');
        console.log(err);
        return NextResponse.json({success: false}, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

Frontend code

```
if (result.success) {
            const base64PDF = result.data;
            const pdfBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(base64PDF).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
            const pdfBlob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            const pdfURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
            window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
}
```